# Приложение для разных версий

Tags: android, gradle

Кто знает ресурсы где описывается принципиально создания приложений для разных версий андроид. Столкнулся м проблемой, создал приложение для 4.x.x и теперь на 5 андроида оно не запускается.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "antonin.juliamusic"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'

    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile files ('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar');

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Покажите gradle файл

Comment: что в стектрейсе при запуске на android 5 (с какой ошибкой закрывается) или что вообще происходит. Оно не запускается  - слишком расплывчато, чтобы сказать наверняка почему.

Comment: Устанавлюется но не включается. Пишет в приложении произошла ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, при создании проекта была указана одна и та же версия sdk как для `minSdkVersion` так и для `targetSdkVersion`. Исправить это можно в файле градл. Вот ссылка на [документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).